# Получение снимка модулей процесса

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, windows-10, ctypes

Использую Python 3.6, psutil. psutil выводит список модулей, но не выводит их PID. Для C++ есть [такое](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/psapi/enumerating-all-modules-for-a-process), но как адаптировать этот код для ctypes? Есть ли примеры? Прошу прощения за совершенно нубские вопросы, уже довольно долго мучаюсь с этой задачей. Исходная задача была в получении PID (и желательно базового адреса) DLL файла, подгружаемого процессом. Или может быть есть способы получить PID модулей без ctypes и кода на C/C++? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Посмотрите [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688936/how-to-get-pid-by-process-name-in-python/26688998#26688998) вариант, возможно это то что вам надо.

Comment: Это не то. Это только для Linux. Нужно для Windows.

Comment: В [документации](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#processes) по psutil вроде бы как есть отображение PID процессов. Примерно так (проверить не могу): `>>> import psutil  >>> [p.info for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if 'python' in p.info['name']]`

Comment: @АлексейПетродий, как вы получаете список модулей процесса через psutil? Вообще по идее, у модулей не может быть PID (Process ID), т.к. это модули процесса, а не процессы, но какой-то ID у них все равно должен быть.

Comment: Вот кстати пример с `EnumProcessModulesEx`: 
 [Is there a way to list all DLLs loaded in Windows by ALL processes using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242053/4752653)

Comment: @insolor через psutil.process_iter().
Как тогда можно приаттачиться к подгруженной процессором dll, если она не имеет pid? Как я нагуглил, нужно получить base address этого модуля. Это возможно сделать?

Comment: @АлексейПетродий, как конкретно вы пробуете делать? `psutil.process_iter()` возвращает итератор объектов `Process`, у каждого из которых есть поле `pid`. Но я так понимаю, что это не то что вам нужно.

Comment: У pymem есть функция 'pymem.process.module_from_name', которая позволяет модифицировать память в пространстве указанной DLL-ки, и которая у меня почему-то не работает. Вот я и пытаюсь провернуть что-то похожее через psutil и ctypes. Я если честно сам не понимаю, что делать, и как, и сильно запутался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с *ctypes* через создание снимка модулей для **текущего** процесса.

```
from ctypes import (
   POINTER, Structure, byref, create_unicode_buffer, c_byte, c_char,
   c_ulong, c_void_p, sizeof, windll
)

INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1
TH32CS_SNAPMODULES   = 8
TH32CS_SNAPMODULES32 = 16

CloseHandle             = windll.kernel32.CloseHandle
CreateToolhel32Snapshot = windll.kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot
FormatMessage           = windll.kernel32.FormatMessageW
GetCurrentProcessId     = windll.kernel32.GetCurrentProcessId
GetLastError            = windll.kernel32.GetLastError
Module32First           = windll.kernel32.Module32First
Module32Next            = windll.kernel32.Module32Next

def getlasterror():
   msg = create_unicode_buffer(0x100)
   num = FormatMessage(0x12FF, None, GetLastError(), 1024, msg, len(msg), None)
   print(msg.value if num else 'Ахтунг! Что-то странное произошло.')

class ModuleSnap(object):
   def __init__(self, pid):
      self._snap = CreateToolhel32Snapshot(
         TH32CS_SNAPMODULES | TH32CS_SNAPMODULES32, pid
      )
      if INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == self._snap:
         raise OSError(getlasterror())
   def __del__(self):
      if not CloseHandle(self._snap):
         getlasterror()
   def __enter__(self):
      return self
   def __exit__(self, e_type, e_value, e_trace):
      del self


class tagMODULEENTRY32(Structure):
   _fields_ = [
      ('dwSize',        c_ulong),
      ('th32ModuleID',  c_ulong),
      ('th32ProcessID', c_ulong),
      ('GlblcntUsage',  c_ulong),
      ('ProccntUsage',  c_ulong),
      ('modBaseAddr',   POINTER(c_byte)),
      ('modBaseSize',   c_ulong),
      ('hModule',       c_void_p),
      ('szModule',      c_char * 256),
      ('_szExePath',    c_char * 260),
   ]
   def __init__(self):
      self.dwSize = sizeof(self)
   @property
   def szExePath(self):
      return str(self._szExePath, 'ascii', 'replace')


if __name__ == '__main__':
   # на месте GetCurrentProcessId можно указать PID нужного процесса
   with ModuleSnap(GetCurrentProcessId()) as hndl:
      me, arr = tagMODULEENTRY32(), []
      ok = Module32First(hndl._snap, byref(me))
      while (ok):
         arr.append({'Module' : me.szExePath, 'BaseAddress' : hex(me.hModule)})
         ok = Module32Next(hndl._snap, byref(me))
      print(arr)
```

Comment: `with ModuleSnap(GetCurrentProcessId()) as hndl:
                                                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`
Код не менялся вообще.

Comment: Видимо у вас криво скопировался код на что, собственно, и указывает ошибка (IndentationError - ошибка отступов).

Comment: Прошу прощения. Не сплю вторые сутки. Всё работает, большое спасибо!